# Typescript extending class in another file

Tags: typescript

I am trying to extend a typescript class in another file like so:

a.ts:

```
module MyModule {
    public Name: string;
    export class MyClassA
    {
    }
}
```

b.ts:

```
module MyModule {
    export class MyClassB extends MyClassA
    {
    }
}
```

But I get the error that MyClassA cannot be found.

Both files are inside my tsconfig.json files array. 
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But I get the error that MyClassA cannot be found.

You probably have a root level `import` or an `export` statement in your file. That makes the file a *module* in the project and disconnects it from the global namespace. So `module MyModule` in file A is not the same as it is in file B. [More on modules](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/modules.html).

*This is a good thing*. You don't want to pollute the global namespace [more](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/tips/outFile.html).

## Solution

Learn to use a module loader. My recommendataion : webpack.

Comment: the `more` link is dead, a bit more of information would be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

I will provide an example how to reference classes from other `.ts` files.

In this example we have four `.ts` files which are modules by default (external modules), except the fourth file `app.ts`

[Typescript Modules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html)

> In TypeScript, just as in ECMAScript 2015, any file containing a
>   top-level import or export is considered a module. Conversely, a file
>   without any top-level import or export declarations is treated as a
>   script whose contents are available in the global scope (and therefore
>   to modules as well).

---

## Example:

We have a `class Man` and a `class Woman` which inherit from `class Human`.
In `app.ts` we create an instance of `Man`.

**Human.ts**

```
export class Human {

    public Name: string;

    constructor(name: string) {
        this.Name = name;
    }


    public WhatIsMyName() {
        console.log(`I am ${this.Name}`);
        return this.Name;
    }
}
```

**Man.ts**

```
import { Human } from "./Human";

export class Man extends Human {
    constructor(name: string) {
        super(name);
    }
}
```

**Woman.ts**

```
import { Human } from "./Human";

    export class Woman extends Human {
        constructor(name: string) {
            super(name);
        }
    }
```

**YourApp.ts**

```
import { Man } from "./man";

const man = new Man("Billy The Kid");
man.WhatIsMyName();
```

Answer (score 2):

Add reference a.ts reference to b.ts file like this:

```
/// <reference path="a.ts" />
module MyModule {
    export class MyClassB extends MyClassA
    {
    }
}
```

or use import like this:

```
import MyModule = require("MyModule")
```

Answer (score 0):

extends MyModule.MyClassA seems to work:

a.ts:

```
module MyModule {
    export class MyClassA {}
}
```

b.ts:

```
///<reference path="a.ts" />
module MyModule {
    export class MyClassB extends MyModule.MyClassA {}
}
```

Not sure if this works everywhere and if it's good practice.